# How to click on a class on a website using Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, class, selenium-webdriver

Needing help getting selenium to click on a javascript widget. It is a website for our customers and i want to automate the process of sending emails.

I got the program to login and get to the page but I can't get it to click on the class "PagerDataRow". I want it to just click it so it can open their information and I can finish the rest I believe. This is my first programming project so forgive how sloppy it is.

```
def autoalert_mine():
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("PagerDataRow odd").click()

    autoalert_mine()
```

My full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver  #Loads Selenium
driver = webdriver.Chrome()     #Opens Browser (Chrome)

import win32com.client as comclt

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time

login = 'rcaldwell@grubbs.com'
password = 'zqxwce132'

def autoalert_login():
    driver.get("https://opportunities.autoalert.com")
    wsh= comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    wsh.SendKeys(login) # send the keys you want
    wsh.SendKeys("{TAB}")
    wsh.SendKeys(password)
    wsh.SendKeys("{TAB}")
    wsh.SendKeys("{TAB}")
    wsh.SendKeys("{ENTER}")

autoalert_login()
##We should be logged into Autoalert.com    

driver.get('https://opportunities.autoalert.com/alert-desk/opportunities')

time.sleep(3)

def autoalert_mine():
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("PagerDataRow odd").click()

autoalert_mine()
```

This is the html I found. highlighting this code selects the whole data table

```
<div id="PagerDiv" class="fit-height-pager fit-width-pager fixed-table" style="height: 499px; overflow: hidden; width: 1012px;">
    <div class="fixed-table-header ui-widget-header" style="height: 25px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="fixed-table-container-inner">
      <table data-rows-count="30" style="width:100%" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-table-pager" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header real">
```

The actual individual rows (Each customers name and info that I can click to view their sheet)

```
<span class="column-title" data-column-key="Action" data-column-name="Action">Action</span>


              </div>
            </th>

        </tr></thead>

        <tbody id="GridData">

            <tr class="PagerDataRow odd                 read  ui-cursor-hand">


                  <td class="text scoreColumn">


                            <input type="hidden" class="DealSheetURL" value="rn=1&amp;e=45a98631-a963-e311-8533-782bcb5c10c8&amp;ds=DS_e17cb6c0-4d38-41da-a506-31e734f0ff33&amp;sn=auto&amp;calc=&amp;snav=False" style="width:0px">`enter code here`
                            <input type="hidden" class="ServiceID" value="0" style="width:0px">    

<span title="97">97</span>


                  </td>

                  <td class="watch-action ">


<button class="watch-action-button row-action-button active" data-entity-id="45a98631-a963-e311-8533-782bcb5c10c8" data-action-type="inline" data-action-id="watch" data-value="True" title="Flag">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-flag">Flag</span>
</button>

                  </td>

                  <td class="text fullNameColumn">

<span title="WANDA APPLON">WANDA APPLON</span>
```

> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".PagerDataRow odd"}
>     (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_class_name` method can't find a combination of classes like you've tried with `"PagerDataRow odd"`, just a single class like:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("PagerDataRow")
```